# Keep the format of numbers in Excel using Buttons extensions

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, data.table, dt

I am using in Shiny [Buttons extension](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/003-tabletools-buttons.html) to download figures in a Excel-File.

```
DTa <- data.table( 
      dataSum()[,1],
      format(round((10^-6)*dataSum()[,-1],2),nsmall = 2,decimal.mark=",",big.mark=".")
           )
   DTa<- DT::datatable( DTa,  extensions=c("Buttons"),options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                               searching = FALSE,
                               dom = 'Bfrtip',
                               #buttons = c('copy','excel')
                               buttons = list(
                                 list(
                                   extend = 'excel', 
                                   text = "Save ", 
                                   title = 'KRB'
                                 ),   list(
                                   extend = 'copy', title = 'krb'
                                 )
                               )
                               ),
                   caption=  paste("Stichtag:", 
                             as.character(sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})KRB.csv", "\\1.\\2.\\3",input$date))))
```

In the first part above, I transform the figures in the *German format*, i.e., I set `,` as a decimal separator and `.` as a thousands separator. In the second part, I call the `extensions Buttons` of `DT`.
In Shiny, the figures look as follows:

[image: Shiny]

**Problem:** After pressing the Save Button in Shiny, all figures with just `,` and without `.` have the wrong format.

[image: Excel screenshot]

For example, after saving *34,21* becomes *3.421*! But *67.809,97* is correct!

How can I keep the format of the figures during the export or save process?

I don't know if it helps:

When I change into the debug mode and execute the second part  `DTa<- DT::datatable( DTa,  extensions ...`  I see the following:

[image: data bevore excel extension]

As one can see the figures in data are characters!

Is it possible to write a JavaScript function in my `server.R` to use the [language.decimal](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.decimal#Examples) option? There is an example [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/128), however I cannot use it exactly.

Comment: Maybe output as CSV?

Comment: I tried the output in  CSV-Format  too, however it dose not look well

Comment: Can you provide reproducible example for `dataSum`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DTa<- DT::datatable(DTa, extensions=c("Buttons"), options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                                                  searching = FALSE,
                                                  dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                  #buttons = c('copy','excel')
                                                  buttons = list(
                                                   list(
                                                        extend = 'excel', 
                                                        text = "Save ", 
                                                        title = 'KRB'
                                                        ), list(
                                                          extend = 'copy', title = 'KRB'
                                                         )
                                                        )
                                                        ),
          caption= paste("Stichtag:", 
                   as.character(sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})KRB.csv", "\\1.\\2.\\3",input$date)))
          ) %>% formatCurrency(-1,' ', digits = 2 , interval = 3, mark = ".", dec.mark = ",")
```

Comment: nice idea excel bottom works well now, but I got an problem with copy bottom! :(